# Declaration and Definition issue

Tags: c, variables, declaration, definition

I know this question has been asked many times,but I don't find any relevant answer.
According to C

```
int x;       //definition

extern int x; //declaration

int  func(void); //declaration
int func(void)  //definition
{

}
```

My first question is if int x is definition,then why compiler shows an redeclaration error

```
header files
int main()
{
     int x,x;      //for this it shows redeclaration error
}
```

And my second question is if I am defining the var x,twice it doesn't show any error

```
header files
int x;
int x;
int main()
{

}
```

I am using window 7 and DevCpp 5.6.2

Edited :

```
header files
int y;
int main()
{
  int x;
}
```

x and y are definition here?

Comment: "header files" is not valid C code. Is that the actual contents of your file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A declaration of a variable of at file scope without an initializer (and without storage class specifier) is a *tentative definition*:

```
int i;
```

It is valid to have multiple tentative definitions of the same variable in the same source file:

```
int i;
int i;
```

the behavior specified by C is as if there is a declaration at the top of the source file and at the end of the source file there is a `int i = 0;`.

At block scope there is no tentative definition and declaring the same variable multiple times in the same block is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question:
`int x` is both declaration and definition, whereas `extern int x` is only declaration.
This is why you get a redeclaration error.

Comment: regarding the second question, I'm not sure... maybe it's because you define global variables... but it's just a guess

Answer (score 1):

Your first code, gets redeclaration error, because, in your case, `x` is having no linkage (local variable) and  as per `C11`, chapter 6.7,

> If an identifier has no linkage, there shall be **no more than one** declaration of the identifier (in a declarator or type specifier) with the same scope and in the same name space,....

Your second code, compiles because the redeclaration is allowed, as both the statements reside in the global scope having external linkage.

Ref:

> If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.